# Graph API to invite users to access SharePoint folder

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I've written a python code to add read permission on the SharePoint folder for a list of users.
This works fine and I get response of each API call in the below format:

{'@odata.context': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(permission)', 'value': [{'@odata.type': '#microsoft.graph.permission', 'id': 'hfhjfjh', 'roles': ['read'], 'grantedTo': {'user': {'email': 'firsts.last@test.com', 'id': '55a04070-fhgf-kjhk-a866-6f11744a463a', 'displayName': 'FirstName LastName'}}}]}

However when I check in the SharePoint folder, I see only few users are being added to the folder. Not all of them have been added.
I've around 20 users which I'm adding on to the different folders. Some folders are getting 14 users added, some are 12 and some are just 2 or 3.

I'm not sure if there is any limitation on calling graph API. there isn't any error code in the response. Hence I'm not able to understand what is going wrong.

Would really appreciate the pointers.

Here is the code which sends the invite:

```
  # create request body using the email id to invite for folder access
    permission_request_body = {
        "roles": ["read"],
        "message": "Here's the file that we're collaborating on.",
        "requireSignIn": "true",
        "sendInvitation": "false",
        "recipients": [
            {
                "email": email_id
            }
        ]
    }

    # Send invite (add permissions)
    folder_invite_url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{vSharepoint_siteID}/drive/items/{sharepoint_folder_id}/invite"   
    print(f"<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Adding {email_id} to the folder {sharepoint_folder_path}")
    permission_response = requests.post(folder_invite_url, headers=sharepoint_headers, json=permission_request_body) 
    print("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Printing Permission Response => ", permission_response.json())
```

Expecting to get all the users added to the SharePoint folder with read access